# Why is swappiness=10 recommended?

Tags: swap

A value of `swappiness=10` is recommended [in Ubuntu's SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F).

Why is a value of 10 is recommended rather than `swappiness=0`?

Are there any pros of 10 or cons of zero?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why most people recommend to reduce swappiness to 10-20?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184217/why-most-people-recommend-to-reduce-swappiness-to-10-20)

Comment: @Mitch That question is about why people recommend to *reduce* swappiness. This question is different; it is asking why swappiness should be *above zero at all*. So this is not asking why people recommend for it to be *so low*; it's asking why the recommendation is *as high as it is.* Because the answer there (quite rationally) disagrees with the argument to reduce swappiness this far, there is *some overlap* with my answer here, but ultimately I think these are separate (albeit related) questions with separate answers.

Comment: @EliahKagan touché :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`swappiness=0` will wait to swap until it is absolutely necessary. Setting a moderate value like `swappiness=10` will cause pages to be swapped from memory to disk somewhat more readily. This can prevent the need to swap a lot at once; such a need can introduce annoying delays.

In addition, often a process runs but does nothing for an extended time. Many daemons (background services) behave this way. You may have a background application that is left unused for a while. And these days some applications are implemented as multiple processes, like Chromium and Google Chrome, where each tab has a separate process behind it (not a separate thread, but a separate *process*). Setting `swappiness` to a value like 10 makes it so these background tasks that are not being actively used are swapped to memory even when they could remain crammed in RAM. Then when a more actively used process needs to allocate more RAM, it can do so more quickly.

In conclusion, allowing processes to be swapped from RAM to disk *earlier* than necessary often confers a performance benefit and *lower* latencies when a process allocates memory. This is at the expense of the time it takes to swap the processes back. But this is usually done much less frequently than a process in active use allocates and releases memory, so the trade-off is often worthwhile.

Comment: You should also take into account your drive's buffer. If you have a SSD with a buffer of 512 MB and 4 GB of RAM. you can probably leave this at 10 without worrying about any performance issues because any program will be able to _almost_ instantly allocate about 1 GB of RAM. I have a SSD with 256 MB buffer and 8 GB of RAM, so I also leave it at 10 because it also guarantees a quick allocation of about 1 GB which I rarely need.