# Can swap settings be adjusted for swap files using the same methods for Swap Partitions?

Tags: swap

Now that Ubuntu (since 17.04) uses a swap file instead of a swap partition, can the swap settings be adjusted with the same methods used for swap partitions?

For example, to set your swap to 40, will

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=40
```

still work?

And will adding `vm.swappiness = 40` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` retain the new settings after restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both. Swappiness will be set the same way for swap files and swap partitions. I would recommend using a separate configuration file in `/etc/sysctl.d/` though.

To check whether the swappiness has been set after reboot, use the following command:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness 
40
```

If you want to test that the swappiness *does* actually change, you can do a simple test as described in this article: https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that.

Take also note of this question discussing the pros and cons of reducing swappiness: [Why most people recommend to reduce swappiness to 10-20?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184217/why-most-people-recommend-to-reduce-swappiness-to-10-20)